# Mini school database with JS revealing module pattern

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, revealing-module-pattern

I tried the module pattern for the first time, with this exercise as a problem to solve: http://exercism.io/exercises/javascript/grade-school/readme

It's a small exercise requiring simple tasks :

> - Add a student's name to the roster for a grade
>
>   - "Add Jim to grade 2."
>   - "OK."
> - Get a list of all students enrolled in a grade
>
>   - "Which students
>       are in grade 2?"
>   - "We've only got Jim just now."
> - Get a sorted list of
>     all students in all grades. Grades should sort as 1, 2, 3, etc., and
>     students within a grade should be sorted alphabetically by name.
>
>   - "Who
>       all is enrolled in school right now?"
>   - "Grade 1: Anna, Barb, and
>       Charlie. Grade 2: Alex, Peter, and Zoe. Grade 3…"

This is the test suite (jasmine based) http://exercism.io/exercises/javascript/grade-school

This is my implementation with the revealing module pattern

```
function School () {
  var rosterDb = {};

  // Private
  var sort = function(gradeNumber) {
    return rosterDb[gradeNumber].sort();
  }

  // Public
  var roster = function() {
    for(var index in rosterDb) { 
      sort(index);
    }
    return rosterDb;
  };

  var add = function(student, grade) {
    if (rosterDb[grade] == undefined) rosterDb[grade] = [];
    rosterDb[grade].push(student);
  };

  var grade = function(grade) {
    if (rosterDb[grade] != undefined) return sort(grade);
    else return rosterDb[grade] = [];
  };

  return {
    roster: roster,
    add: add,
    grade: grade
  };
}

module.exports = School;
```

I just had two objectives : 1/ make it pass all tests 2/ use the revealing module pattern. The first part is easy to verify, but the second one is harder. I would like some opinions on that